# For cycle with expect and variable evaluation

Tags: linux, shell-script, expect

I want to execute a script remotely with expect and a for loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10

spawn ssh root@10.1.31.11
expect "password: "
send "pass\n"
expect "$ "
send "for i in `ls` ;\n"
send "do\n"
send "   STRLENGTH=$(echo -n $i | wc -m);\n"
send "   if [ $STRLENGTH -ge 35 ];\n"
send "   then echo ok \"$i\";\n"
send "   fi\n"
send "done\n"
```

But it gives me this error:

```
can't read "i": no such variable
    while executing
"send "   STRLENGTH=$(echo -n $i | wc -m);\n""
    (file "./script.sh" line 10)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect` is telling you that it tried to substitute `$i` for a value, but didn't find the variable `i`. This is not your intention: you wanted to send it literally for the remote shell to make the substitution. Escape the `$` character with a backslash to make `expect` pass it literally.

Consider using [`sshpass`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) instead of `expect` too.

Answer (score 1):

gronostaj is the right answer. Note,
you can simplify sending a series of lines into one multi-line string literal. See the [wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/TCL+for+beginners#6e618ceae12641f442d7e6dc76acefb031178458facf2c836c2be8b1f4c3071c).

```tcl
send { for i in `ls`
 do
    STRLENGTH=$(echo -n $i | wc -m)
    if [ $STRLENGTH -ge 35 ]
    then echo ok "$i"
    fi
 done
}
```

Using `{}` to enclose a string instead of `""` preserves newlines and `$` and so on. However, you still need to escape `\`,  `{`, and `}` with `\`.